# Display result of search within view

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a page where I display all my clients.  It uses paginate and only displays 16 clients per page.  As such I have provided realtime search functionality.

When a search is perform, the option selected from the results triggers the following

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/returnClient",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "html",
        data: {
            value : ui.item.value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.container').fadeOut().html(data.html).fadeIn();
        }
    });
}
```

That essentially calls the following function

```
public function returnClient(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $selectedClient = $request->input('value');
        $client = Client::where('clientName', $selectedClient)->first();

        $html = View::make('clients.search', $client)->render();
        return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
    }
}
```

If I output the client variable above, I can see all the details for this particular client.  This is then being passed to the partial clients.search.
Within clients.search, if I do

```
{{dd($client)}}
```

I get Undefined variable: client.  Why does it not get the parsed Object within the view?

Many thanks

Comment: not sure if you are making real use of the API here. I think a better way is to render the HTML inside the view, then the API will call the endpoint, and receives some data, and this data is filled inside the view through Javascript. Passing the complete HTML is killing the idea of the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are improperly passing `$client` to the view. The [Views documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views) shows how to properly pass data via an associative array. The [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/View/Factory.html#method_make) confirm that an array is what is expected.

Do this instead:

```
public function returnClient(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $selectedClient = $request->input('value');
        $client = Client::where('clientName', $selectedClient)->first();

        $html = View::make('clients.search', ['client' => $client])->render();
        return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
    }
}
```

Also, as a point of habit you may want to consider using `dump()` instead of `dd()`.

Comment: For others information: `dump()` is the function `dd()` calls behind the scenes so it's essentially the same thing without dieing and without accepting variable number of args.